# Install new jboss server in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Anybody knows how to install a jboss 4.2 server in new eclipse luna?

When you try to add new server, jboss option doesnt appear.

I have installed jboss tools and then jboss AS option is available, but i just want jboss.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 9):

Install [JBoss Tool for Luna](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools-luna). The only feature you need is JBossAS Tool.

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse Luna is distributed without the useful "Generic JBoss configuration" server options.
However, I tried to import from Kepler version and... it works! :P
My steps:
1) Download Eclipse Kepler J2EE edition (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2)
2) Download Eclipse Luna J2EE edition (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar)
3) Extract both downloaded zip files.
4) Copy org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.jboss_1.6.100.v20130422_1357 folder and org.jboss.netty_3.2.5.Final-20130531-2315.jar file from plugins folder of Eclipse Kepler to plugins folder of Eclipse Luna.
5) Start Eclipse Luna, do a poker face and add Jboss to the server view :)

Happy working.

Answer (score 4):

Kepler only has Jboss AS 5 and below. Another approach I found - For JBoss AS 7 and 8 server runtimes, point your eclipse to the update site url: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/,

This has so many components.. all we need for server integration is: JBoss Web and Java EE Development -> JBoss AS Tools. If you select only this component and install, its a small download without the full blown jboss tools installation.

Comment: Thank you! This is way what I needed. It's easy to find the tools but it's a pain to install them all...

Answer (score 1):

```
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600
```

In IDE do next:

> Help -> Install new software

In this window click "ADD" and add URL:

> http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/

In list check "Jboss Web and Java EE Development"
After those operations eclipse should be restarted.

Y have new env in IDE for start apps in JBoss. 
To be continue

==> 73